# unable to get the path(url) of image with createIcon() method

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

So when i'm tried to put an icon to my button with `createIcon()` method that i declared inside of the button's class, it works fine.

**BUT,**

when i try to put the method in another class (say `Utils.java`), so that i don't need to re-declare the method in the class where the object needs icon, i get this message.

> Unable to load image: /images/Save16.gif
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

**there's more message if needed*

**this is the button's class with createIcon() method inside**

```
public class Toolbar extends JToolBar implements ActionListener{
   private final JButton saveBtn;
   
   public Toolbar() {
      saveBtn = new JButton();

      saveBtn.setIcon(createIcon("/images/Save16.gif"));

      saveBtn.setToolTipText("Save");
      saveBtn.addActionListener(this);
      add(saveBtn);
   }

   private ImageIcon createIcon(String path) { 
      URL url = getClass().getResource(path);
    
      if(url == null) {
         System.err.println("Unable to load image: " + path);
      }
    
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
    
      return icon;
  }
}
```

**this is the createIcon() method that i'm trying to declare in another class**

```
public class Utils {
    public static ImageIcon createIcon(String path) {
        URL url = System.class.getResource(path);

        if(url == null) {
                System.err.println("Unable to load image: " + path);
        }

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);

        return icon;
    }
}
```

which changed the `setIcon()` method into:

```
saveBtn.setIcon(Utils.createIcon("/images/Save16.gif"));
```

from what i analyzed in the message the problem is  might be the `url` which can't get the `path` from my button's class, i've tried several alternatives but it's still didn't work. how should i properly set this up? thanks

Comment: did you put `/images/` in the resources folder? Or was it directly next to the class the method was declared in (before moving it to Utils?) Seems the path used would be fine if you specified `/images` as  a resources dir.

Comment: I'm so sorry, i don't really get what you are asking. But, i put the images package in the same folder as the source code. But thanks a lot Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource(path);
```

because you get the class of your Toolbar class, which is where all your other classes/files are located.

This doesn't work:

```
URL url = System.class.getResource(path);
```

because the "System" class is found in the JDK not with your application classes.

I would guess you could try:

```
URL url = Utils.class.getResource(path);
```