# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, window

Not Sure what is wrong. I have the console error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
    
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
    
public class TrippieMain {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TrippieMain();
    }

    public TrippieMain(){           
        createUI();
    }

    public void createUI(){
            
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        window.setLayout(null);
            
        JPanel trippiePanel = new JPanel();
        trippiePanel.setBounds(100, 220, 200, 200);
        trippiePanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        window.add(trippiePanel);
            
        ImageIcon trippie = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("trippie200x2001.png"));
            
        JButton trippieButton = new JButton();
        trippieButton.setBackground(Color.black);
        trippieButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        trippieButton.setBorder(null);
        trippieButton.setIcon(trippie);
        trippiePanel.add(trippieButton);
            
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where is trippie200x2001.png? Does that call to #getResource actually return something?

Comment: When you have an exception, you need to put the full stack trace into your question.

Comment: trippie200x2001.png needs to be in the same package as the TrippieMain class.  See [the Class.getResource documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

Comment: unrelated: it's __wrong__ to not use a layoutManager!

Comment: @tgdavies while this is true, in fairness to the OP, the problem goes beyond a simple NPE. The root cause of the problem is not understanding what to expect invoking `getResource()`. Answering why this method is returning null can't simply be answered by the post you linked in your comment. A better link would've been this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/65372046/2851311

Comment: Reed, I answered your question with enough details for you to understand the entirety of your problem. One thing I didn't mention in my answer is to break up linked chained method calls to make it easy to troubleshoot. Although in this case that's trivial (`getClass()` and `getClassLoader()` will never return `null`), in most cases calling each method separately will make it easier to troubleshoot these problems. In fact, there those in the dev community who think that method chaining is bad news.

Comment: @hfontanez true, I hope that that people will come back from that link and change their question to "why is getResource returning null", but perhaps that's unrealistic. I agree your link is better.

Comment: @tgdavies that's why I posted an answer to this question. It is obvious the OP doesn't know how to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: @VGR The image doesn't need to be in the same package at the main class. It needs to be at the root location of the class path; in this case `src`.

Comment: @hfontanez Ah, you’re right.  I didn’t see that Reed was using ClassLoader.getResource rather than Class.getResource.  But I would argue that the better solution is to remove the `.getClassLoader()` part and keep the image in the same package.

Answer (score -1):

Null Pointer Exceptions are not that hard to fix. Most of the time, the exception message tells you what the problem is. This is not the case for this issue. However, the exception message tells you enough to figure this out.

Long story short, the `NullPointerException` is thrown because you don't understand how to use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` in the proper context. For what you are trying to do, you *probably* don't even need to use that. You could simply pass a simpler, valid argument to the `ImageIcon` constructor.

Let's check the `ImageIcon` constructors to see which one you could use.

```
ImageIcon(); // Creates an uninitialized image icon.
ImageIcon(byte[]); // Creates an ImageIcon from an array of bytes which were read from an image file containing a supported image format, such as GIF, JPEG, or (as of 1.3) PNG.
ImageIcon(Image); // Creates an ImageIcon from an image object.
ImageIcon(String); // Creates an ImageIcon from the specified file. The String can be a file name or a file path.
ImageIcon(URL); // Creates an ImageIcon from the specified URL.
```

Based on the argument you are using in your post, it seems you should pass either the file name or the file path directly into the `ImageIcon` constructor. At worst, you can pass the full path to the image.

If your image is inside your project, one way to get the full path is by using `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. This property returns the path from where the Java application was launched. This is basically your project. This is a great approach because this path will most likely change. For example, during development, this path can change between developers in a team. Then, when the code is deployed, it will most likely be in a different path. The important thing is that in every case, this path will be resolved by the system automatically for you. You can also pass a relative path from the project's root and should work just the same.

Then, all you need to do is append the relative path to your image for the project's root directory. Do this and your problem will be solved.

So... assuming you have an "images" folder as a subfolder of your project's root directory, you need to replace this line:

```
 ImageIcon trippie = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("trippie200x2001.png"));
```

with something like this:

```
ImageIcon trippie = new ImageIcon("./images/trippie200x2001.png");
```

or with something like this:

```
ImageIcon trippie = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/images/trippie200x2001.png");
```

Using your code with my own image, I was able to successfully launch your application

[image]

**UPDATE**:

In my excitement, I forgot to answer the fundamental question for this issue: How do you fix the *location is "null"* problem using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()`? This is simple... When you invoke `getResource()`, the expected behavior is that "resources" must be contained in the `src` path for your project. Anything not in the classpath, will not be found; hence the NPE.

Since you were passing "trippie200x2001.png", this image is expected to be inside the `src` folder in your project. For my example, since I was using "images/trippie200x2001.png", the expected behavior is that "images" be a package inside `src` and the image in question be inside that package (folder).